# How to show a random number to 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, random, numbers, format

I am making a program that generates a random number which then is shown to 2 decimal places, I have attempted this but it always comes up with an error.

This is my code:

```
Random r = new Random();
        double ran = r.Next();
        int egg;
        egg = Console.ReadLine;

        Console.WriteLine("The Random number is " + egg);


        egg = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine(egg);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("price {0:C}", egg));


        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This code contains too many compile errors. fix them and come back.

Comment: Reading the error message would be a good first step.

Comment: 1) `ReadLine` is a method you are missing `( ) ` . 2) it returns a `string`. you cannot assign the return value to `egg` because it is of type `int`

Comment: Umm... you are not doing what you say you are. The random number is discarded, and you are simply writing out the value read from the console window. Oh, and you are trying to store a `double` in an `int`.

Comment: Well, at least the string formatting is right. `{0:C}` will show up with two decimal places and a currency symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a number with decimal places you should use `NextDouble()`method.

```
Random r = new Random();
double egg = r.NextDouble();
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("price {0}", egg.ToString("n2")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version which does what your comment states at the beginning.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:C}", r.Next()));
    }
}
```